# Debounce function returning multiples times

Tags: javascript, function, debouncing

**Context:** It's the first time I try to implement a `debounce()` function and probably I misunderstood something, because the function it's calling my API multiple times, although the delay it's been aplied, my code:

```
async updateSelectAll(value) {
  const execute = this.debounce(async () => {
    await this.getTotalDaeMunicipio(this.filtroDaeMunicipio);
    await this.gerarGraficoMunicipio();
  }, 1000);
  execute();
},

debounce(func, wait) {
  let timer = null;
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(func, wait);
  };
}
```

The function `updateSelectAll` it's called everytime the user clicks on a checkbox, this is working.

**The problem:** when the user clicks on the checkbox, the function `updateSelectAll` it's called, after 1 second(1000ms), the API is called through the function `execute()` which have the `debounce` function, but when the user click multiple times on the checkbox, the API is called multiple times.

**Expected behavior:** when the checkobox it's clicked multiple times, was meant to do just one call to the API.

Comment: Use observables!

Comment: I think the problem is where you declare the timer variables. Try declare it out of the debounce function scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a local variable `timer` in the debounce function that the inner function closes over and has access to.

```
debounce(func, wait) {
  let timer = null;
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(func, wait);
  };
}
```

The problem is, though, that you invoke `this.debounce()` multiple times, which is not sharing this `timer`. You need to share this timer between invocations of debounce to achieve your goal

Comment: It's worked! I put the `timer` variable in the `data` of Vue and delete the `this.timer = null` and worked! Thanks man! :D